Question about npm warnings and vulnerabilities during package installation
I ran npm i in my project directory and received a series of warnings and vulnerabilities. Could someone help me understand what these warnings mean and how to address them appropriately?
Here's the output I received:
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile
...
116 vulnerabilities (4 low, 31 moderate, 61 high, 20 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.


I'm particularly concerned about the deprecated packages and the high number of vulnerabilities reported. How should I proceed to fix these issues? Should I run npm audit fix or npm audit fix --force? What are the potential risks associated with each option?
Any guidance on how to handle these warnings and vulnerabilities would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

This is the repository I cloned: https://github.com/ionicthemes/improved-ux-for-ionic-apps-with-skeleton-loading-screens?tab=readme-ov-file
